# How to use Enum.Parse in windows phone 7 in a proper way?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, enums

I want to parse some data into enum but I'm stumbling upon a problem. Namely, when I try this code:

```
Languages lang = Enum.Parse(typeof(Languages), languageChooser.SelectedItem, true);
```

I get info that it has some invalid arguments. I think there is a problem with the first one but in every tutorial I've found the first arg looks like this.
Any help or advice?

Comment: What error message _specifically_ do you get? What is the declaration of `Languages`? What is `languageChooser`? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't think that overload is supported in WP7. Unfortunately they've removed WP7 support info from the documentation so it's hard to tell by inspection.

Comment: [MSDN Enum.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't get any special error message, my code's just underscored with red line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your second parameter, not the first. `languageChooser.SelectedItem` more than likely returns an instance of `object` rather than `string`. I'm not sure what type you're using to back your `languageChooser`, so it's hard to say what the proper fix is. It could be any of the following:

```
// languageChooser is bound to an IEnumerable<string>
var lang = 
    Enum.Parse(typeof(Languages), languageChooser.SelectedItem as string, true);

// languageChooser is bound to something with a proper ToString() implementation
var lang = 
    Enum.Parse(typeof(Languages), languageChooser.SelectedItem.ToString(), true);

// languageChooser is an IEnumerable<SomeOtherType> where SomeOtherType has a property
// that indicates the language
var obj = languageChooser.SelectedItem as SomeOtherType;
var lang = Enum.Parse(typeof(Languages), obj.SomeLanguageProperty, true);
```